# Storage_Error on array declaration

Tags: ada

I've got an issue with a function I've written in Ada 95. When the function is called, I get a Storage_Error before the first statement executes (which is a log message). By commenting out declarations and testing, I have narrowed the problem down to the following line:

```
Field_Values : Message_Field_Array;
```

The relevant type definitions for Message_Field_Array are as follows:

```
type Extract_Field_Type is
record
    Field      : String ( 1 .. Comms.Buffer_Type'Size ) := ( others => ' ' );
    Char_Count : Integer := 0;
end record;

type Message_Field is ( MESSAGE, DATETIME, EPOCH, GPS_CLASS, OBJECT_NAME, TRAIN, LAT, LNG );

type Message_Field_Array is array ( Message_Field'Range ) of Extract_Field_Type;
```

I've clearly missed something. What is wrong with what I've set up here?

Comment: You're declaring an array of a record containing an array. What is Comms.Buffer_Type'Size?

Comment: Note that `'Size` gives you the size of the type in _bits_.  Still, I don't see the problem unless `Comms.Buffer_Type` is huge.

Comment: Yeah, turned out it was rather large. Still, I didn't expect a storage_error. My solution was to change the type of the array to an access type for Extract_Field_Type.

Comment: The default size of the stack depends on the OS. GNAT has `-fstack-check` which usually gives a more helpful error than `Storage_Error`. If you use a GPR, this should be in package Builder (since it’s used at both compile and link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sources are incomplete, but my guess is that your error is to use `'Size`, where you mean `'Length`.